# How can I get my clouds.yaml file from OpenStack Horizons?

Tags: terraform, openstack, authentication

OpenStack can export a configuration file called [clouds.yaml](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/config/configuration.html). How do I export this file from the Horizon's interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps,

1. Log into Horizons
2. On the left bar click **Identity**.
3. Under Identity, click **Application Credentials**.
4. Click the **+ Create Application Credentials** button at the top
5. You must at least give a name.
6. Click **"Create Application Credential"** at the bottom of the page.
7. Click **Download clouds.yaml**

And you'll typically want to put this file either,

- `$HOME/.config/openstack/clouds.yaml`
- `/etc/openstack/clouds.yaml`