# Is it possible to download a "clouds.yaml" file for an Application Credential that already exists?

Tags: openstack, authentication

When I log into OpenStack Horizons, under **Identity** → **Application Credentials** I can see the name of the credential but I do not have the `clouds.yaml` file anymore. Can I download the `clouds.yaml` for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No

You can not download the `clouds.yaml` file for an Application Credential that already exists. [You'll have to delete it and create a new Application Credential.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17321/18965).